# Test_anagram function

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

I'm wanting to define a function called test_anagram that takes no arguments.
It should call a previous function 'anagram' and test if it's working correctly.
The function needs to print out whether it's passed or not with true/false underneath each pair of words. (so far I have it to show one of the anagrams as false to test.

My code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


def anagram(str1,str2):
 # string to list
  str1 = list(str1.lower())
  str2 = list(str2.lower())

  #sort list
  str1.sort()
  str2.sort()

  #join list back to string
  str1 = ''.join(str1)
  str2 = ''.join(str2)

  return str1 == str2

print(anagram('trainer', 'terrain')) #true
print(anagram('trainer', 'shoe')) #false
```

(this bottom half is what I'm having the problem with).

```
def test_anagram():
   strings = [("plane","panel"),("traps","parts"),("state","man"),                                                            ("nails","snail"),("reset","trees"),("later","alert")]        strings
   for str1,str2 in strings: 
   print(str1,str2) # print each string
   anagram(str1,str2) 


test_anagram() 
print(anagram('plane', 'panel'))

print(anagram('traps', 'parts'))

print(anagram('state', 'man'))

print(anagram('nails', 'snail'))

print(anagram('later', 'alert'))
```

At the moment it prints to the terminal like this:

```
plane panel
traps parts
state man
nails snails
reset trees
later alert
True
True
False
True
True
```

Where as I'm wanting it to print like this:

```
plane panel
True
traps parts
True
state man
False
nails snails
True
reset trees
True
later alert
True
```

I'm not sure how to do this so any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thank you.

Comment: Why exactly did you just delete almost all text from your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
   for str1,str2 in strings: 
   print(str1,str2) # print each string
   anagram(str1,str2)
```

use

```
   for str1,str2 in strings:                       # OK - no change
       print(str1,str2) # print each string        # added indentation
       print(anagram(str1,str2))                   # added indentation + print()
```

(and delete all now already redundant lines after the line `test_anagram()`.)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Please consider to upvote my answer, too, if it was useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation is the key.

```
def test_anagram():
   strings = [("plane","panel"),("traps","parts"),("state","man"),                                                            ("nails","snail"),("reset","trees"),("later","alert")]        strings
   for str1,str2 in strings: 
       print(str1,str2) # print each string
       print(anagram(str1,str2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following answer asumes the indentation is correct (it wasn't when I answered it)

Well, your `anagram` function doesn't print anything. It just returns `True` or `False`, right? So you do this:

```
test_anagram() 
print(anagram('plane', 'panel'))

print(anagram('traps', 'parts'))

print(anagram('state', 'man'))

print(anagram('nails', 'snail'))

print(anagram('later', 'alert'))
```

You're calling the `test_anagram` function that only prints the strings and then calls `anagram`, but `test_anagram` doesn't do anything with the value returned by that call to the `anagram` function (it just calls it). After that, you manually do the `print(anagram('plane', 'panel'))`, and that's why you see the `True`, `False`...

You shouldn't need to manually print all those calls to `anagram` if your function `test_anagram` did the printing:

```
def test_anagram():
   strings = [("plane","panel"),
              ("traps","parts"),
              ("state","man"),                                                                  
              ("nails","snail"),
              ("reset","trees"),
              ("later","alert")]
   for str1,str2 in strings: 
       print(str1,str2) # print each string (as you're alredy doing)
       print(anagram(str1,str2))  # Print whether is an anagram or not
```

Answer (score 0):

### Formatting

Upon initial inspection, it looks like you forgot to close your brackets on your list, but the rest of the list is actually just about 60 spaces to the right. That's a bit of a no-no, but not a huge issue. What IS an issue, however, is that you have the variable "strings" sitting at the end of the line, after your list. That should be removed if the code is to run at all. Additionally, you should use a "\" if your line exceeds 90 characters or so, as I do below.

### Indents (this is Python, after all)

Secondly, Nf4r isn't wrong, your indenting is off a bit, but even that doesn't solve your problem, because you'll need to print the result of your anagram function (which Nf4r does, but doesn't say) below where you print each string.

### Printing

Printing is great, but you've added too many print statements here to get what you want. The 5 print statements after your function call are superfluous. The following will work in the way you desire:

```
def test_anagram():
  strings = [("plane","panel"),("traps","parts"),("state","man"), \
           ("nails","snail"),("reset","trees"),("later","alert")]
  for str1,str2 in strings:
      print(str1,str2) # print each string
      print(anagram(str1,str2))

test_anagram()
```